# Sign an iOS app created by another developer

Tags: ios, app-store

I am working on an update to existing app on the iOS app store. The app was originally created by a contracting firm, and the distribution certificate and app id was created by them. We need to push an update, but can't get the Certificate.p12 from them. We do have control over the iTunes Connect account, though.

If we can't get in touch with them to send over the .p12, do we have any recourse outside of pulling down the app and creating a brand new one? The major drawback here is losing existing user base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to iTunes connect account.. you should go to the iOS provisioning portal (https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) and:

1. First create a new certificate
2. edit the distribution certificate and select your newly created certificate
3. Download the distribution certificate
4. sign the package with the new distribution certificate you just created

Hope that helps, let us know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Perfect, Alejandro. Got everything working. Thanks for the assist.